# How can I return a truth value to the "base function" in recursion?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

My function looks like this:

```
def func(x):
    for i in range(x+1 to x+10):
        if (condition):
            return True
        else:
            func(i)
    return False
```

Here, when we return True or False, the return value of the previous recursive call is not affected.

I want to do: if a recursive function returns True, the "base case function" should also return True immediately.

A workaround I've found is using a nonlocal variable:

```
var = False
def func(x):
    nonlocal var
    for i in range(x+1 to x+10):
        if (condition):
            var = True
        else:
            func(i)
    return var
```

But is there a nicer way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just this.

```
def func(x):
    for i in range(x+1 to x+10):
        if (condition):
            return True
        elif func(i):
            return True
    return False
```

Do use the return value of `func(i)` as a boolean value.